# Adding function description eclipse CDT

Tags: function, eclipse-cdt

What I want to do is add some comments at the function definition and see it as a description when I hover over the function.

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an outstanding enhancement request in CDT.  See:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=281437
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=251050
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=48215

You could try using the plugin mentioned here:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=48215#c4

The plugin is unsupported, but apparently working.  I'm planning on trying to install it myself.